# Playing random movieclips gives Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, runtime-error

I have an AS3 FLA file of a face. The eyes move randomly by playing different movieclips of eye movements from an array. The code is on the timeline. I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
   at TVCR_fla::eyes_4/playEyes()
   at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
   at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

The error doesn't stop the code from doing what it's supposed to, but I'd like to know what's causing it.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
stop();

var eyeArray:Array = new Array();

eyeArray[0] = eyeBlink1;
eyeArray[1] = eyeBlink2;
eyeArray[2] = eyeBlink3;
eyeArray[3] = eyeLeft;
eyeArray[4] = eyeRight;
eyeArray[5] = eyeWide;

var i:int = 0;

var eyeTimer:Timer = new Timer(100);

eyeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playEyes);

function playEyes(event:TimerEvent):void{
for(i=0; i<eyeArray.length; i++)
{
    var randomEye:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);        
    eyeArray[randomEye].play();
}
}

eyeTimer.start();
```

Comment: Please clarify what your goal is. What are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array `eyeArray` has 6 elements. In this line, you access an element:

```
eyeArray[randomEye].play();
```

The variable that determines the index is defined in the line above:

```
var randomEye:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
```

The value of this random variable is between 0 and 299 (inclusive)

That's way bigger than the length of your array.

From your question is unclear what your intention is or what the structure of the project looks like, which makes it hard to suggest a fix.

I **guess** that you are trying to pick a random frame from each Movieclip, which all have 300 frames in total. To do that, you should pass the random variable to `gotoAndPlay()` which you should be calling instead of `play`. Use the variable from the for loop index to get to the element of the array.

Comment: This definitely looks like a good guess. Spend some time trying to make this work. When messing around with arrays if I get this error, I put trace calls throughout to see if my array is as long as I think it is.

Comment: That was it. Too high a number. Thanks for your help!